# Solidity 4.24, uint plus

Tags: solidity

May I know why I can't do additional in uint for solidity 4.24?

```
function ToUint(bytes memory value) internal pure returns (uint) {
    uint r;
    for (uint i = value.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        r = (r << 8) + uint(value[i]);
    return r;
}
```

I might have over simplified my code and it doesn't exhibit the problem. The original code was above. As soon as I took out (r << 8) +, every thing works.

The << 8 is not an issue. Because it failed even when I have r + uint(value[I])

The length of bytes array is only 6, and all bytes value are < 0x7F

Comment: Could you post the code and the error?

Comment: What is the incentive for giving an upvote here??? There is no minimal coding example which reproduces the described problem, which shouldn't even take place under normal circumstances!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have problems with the loop

```
for (uint i = value.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Since `i` is unsigned once it reaches 0 in the next iteration it will wrap to a very large number becuase `i` cannot be a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

It does work. You can add uint as per [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#integers).
I also tried it in Remix.

Answer (score 1):

You were accessing the elements of `value` wrong, which was causing the reversion.

Here's a working version:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract BytesToUint {

    function toUint(bytes _value) external pure returns (uint) {
        return toUint_(_value);
    }

    function toUint_(bytes memory _value) internal pure returns (uint) {
        uint256 r;

        for(uint256 i = 0; i < _value.length; i++) {
            r += uint256(_value[i]) << (i * 8);
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```